# Sortable Portlet Update Query

Tags: php, jquery

I am attempting to update some sortable divs that are connected with `connectwith`.  I have done a single table before and the update query works, but when mutiple divs are involved it gets tricky.  The problem is I have a field in the database called `div` that needs to update as well with whatever div the sortable object is getting dropped into AS WELL AS put it in a specific order within that div.

EDIT: SOOO, how can I create a sortable update query for multiple div.id locations?

The results I am getting from the code work for just updating the order inside one div, but across multiple divs there is no update.  Plus, I'm not exactly sure of the easiest way to find the div I moved the content to and save that to the database.

Okay, so here's the code I have so far for just updating the order within one div:

```
$(".heriyah").sortable({ 
    handle : '.handle',
    connectWith: ".heriyah",
    revert: "invalid",
    update : function () { 
        var order = $('.heriyah').sortable('serialize'); 
        $("#info").load("admin/sortable.php?"+order); 
    } 
});
```

And the PHP:

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) : 
    $sql[] = "UPDATE `temp` SET `order` = $position WHERE `id` = $item"; 
endforeach; 
print_r ($sql);
```

And the HTML/PHP to produce the content (using alot of PHP and JQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    $('div.heriyah').each(function() { 
    $(this).html('<div class="add"><div id="add_button_container"><div id="add_button" class="edit_links">+ ADD NEW CONTENT</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="placeable" style="height:20px;background-color:#fff;"></div></div>');

    var curID = $(this).attr('id');//get the id before you go into fallr

$('.add').click(function() {
$.fallr('show', {
    content     :  '<iframe width="620" height="600" src="<? echo $URL ?>/manage_content.php?pageID=<? echo $pageID; ?>&div='+ curID +'"></iframe>',
    width       : 620 + 5, // 100 = for width padding
    height         : 600,
    closeKey        : true,
    closeOverlay    : true,
    buttons     : {}
    }); 
 });    
}); 
})();
<?
include_once('system/js/dbc.php');
$pageID = $_REQUEST['pageID'];
$getdiv2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp WHERE pageID = '$pageID' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdiv2)) 
 {
   echo "$('#{$row['div']}.heriyah').append('<div class=sortable id=listItem_{$row['id']}><div id=heriyah_content class=sortable_header>{$row['title']}<br>{$row['maintext']}<div id=heriyah_handle class=handle></div><a onClick=edit_{$row['id']}();return false><div id=heriyah_content_hover></div></a></div></div>');\n";
 }
?>
</script>
<script>
$(".heriyah").sortable({ 
    handle : '.handle',
    connectWith: ".heriyah",
    revert: "invalid",
    update : function () { 
    var order = $('.heriyah').sortable('serialize'); 
    $("#info").load("admin/sortable.php?"+order); 
  } 
});
</script>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Do I need to clarify anything for anyone?

Comment: Yes. Please put actual question inside your post.

Comment: Agree with Tadeck. What results are you getting by using your code and what kind of results are desired?

Comment: Will the order of the items be saved automatically when the `update` event happens, or it will be saved when a button is clicked? Also, please share the HTML for this.

Comment: Okay, I will update this question, but for now I will tell @Shef, the `update` happens as soon as the item is dragged and dropped into a droppable area.

Comment: @drummer392 It might overload, but it is manageable. Update the question with the HTML and I will take a look at it. :)

Comment: Thanks, I realize it is alot of code, but if you have any questions I will be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have produced something based on the jQuery UI [connect-lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/connect-lists.html) example.

I have not implemented the backend calling or database side components but I'm sure you can work that out.  I am only interested in capturing what has moved and to where.

The **receive** event is triggered when you drag items between lists so we can use that.

We also need to catch the **update** event but are not interested in items that are already being dealt with by the **receive** event.  To do this we need to check to see if *ui.sender* is undefined (as it will be for all non-connected list transfers).  However it seems that the **update** event calls all the sortable containers when the update has completed. We only want to capture the data when the updated item's parent is the same as the list receiving the **update** event trigger.  (I hope that makes sense!)

In summary the **receive** event will be used to capture all the inter connect-list transfers and the **update** event will capture any sorting that happens within an element list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3  { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
    #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            update: function(event, ui){
               if(($(ui.sender).attr('id') == undefined)&&($(this).attr('id') == ui.item.parent().attr('id'))){
                   alert('UPDATE ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' ' + (ui.item.index()+1) + ' ' + $(ui.item).text());
               }
            },
            receive: function(event, ui){
               alert('RECEIVE: ' + $(ui.sender).attr('id') + '=>' + $(this).attr('id') + ' ' + (ui.item.index()+1) + ' ' + $(ui.item).text());
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>

</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">F</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">G</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">H</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">I</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">J</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">K</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">L</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">M</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">N</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">O</li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, I will award you 50 rep, also: would you just send an ajax request using the `.attr('id')`?

Comment: If you wanted to capture the current state of your lists I think you would need to send at least 3 things to the backend.  The id of the destination list, the position of the item in the destination list and a unique identifier for item that was transfered (if the item value was unique you could use that). e.g. you would probably use a POST with a data map of key/value pairs but if you were using a GET method you could call something like "admin/sortable.php?dest=sortable2&pos=2&val=L"